# PHP respond to SSDP

Tags: php, networking, ssdp

In PHP, is it possible to respond to SSDP requests?

I need a client device (also written in PHP) to be able to search for the main device (also written in PHP -- sitting on the same network).

Basically, I need a way of detecting the main device's local IP as it's not always known which IP the device has been assigned.

Comment: not very clear what the actual question is, PHP runs on the server so cannot really be considered a `client device` and what is the `main` device??

Comment: Two Docker containers on the same network running the same PHP application. As an example, user visits /connect on one application and should be able to discover the second application's IP address.